# `knitr_out, `file_out` and `vis_drake_graph` usage in R:drake

Tags: drake-r-package

I'm trying to understand how to use `knitr_out`, `file_out` and `vis_drake_graph` properly in `drake`.

I have two questions.

#### Q1: Usage of `knitr_out` and `file_out` to create `markdown` reports

While a code like this works correctly for one of my smaller projects:

```
make_hyp_data_aggregated_report <- function() {
        render(
                input = knitr_in("rmd/hyptest-is-data-being-aggregated.Rmd"),
                output_file = file_out("~/projectname/reports/01-hyp-test.html"),
                quiet = TRUE
        )
}

plan <- drake_plan(
        ...
        ...
        hyp_data_aggregated_report = make_hyp_data_aggregated_report()
        ...
        ...
)
```

[image]

Exactly similar code in my large project (with ~10+ reports) doesn't work *exactly* right. i.e., while the reports get built, the `knitr_in` objects don't get displayed as the blue squares in the graph using `drake::vis_drake_graph()` in my large project.

Both projects use the `drake::loadd(....)` within the markdown to get the objects from cache.

Is there some code in `vis_drake_graph` that removes these squares once the graph gets busy?

#### Q2: `file_out` objects in `vis_drake_graph`

Is there a way to display the `file_out` objects themselves as circles/squares in `vis_drake_graph`?

#### Q3: packages showing up in `vis_drake_graph`

Is there a way to avoid `vis_drake_graph` from printing the packages explicitly? (Basically anything with the `::`)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Q1

Every literal file path needs its own `knitr_in()` or `file_out()`. If you have one function with one `knitr_in()`, even if you use the function multiple times, that still only counts as one file path. I recommend writing these keywords at the plan level, e.g.

```r
plan <- drake_plan(
  r1 = render(knitr_in("report1.Rmd"), output_file = file_out("report1.html")),
  r2 = render(knitr_in("report2.Rmd"), output_file = file_out("report2.html")),
  r3 = render(knitr_in("report3.Rmd"), output_file = file_out("report3.html"))
)
```

### Q2

They should appear unless you set `show_output_files = FALSE` in `vis_drake_graph()`.

### Q3

No, but if it's any consolation, I do regret the decision to track namespaced functions and objects at all in `drake`. `drake`'s approach is fundamentally suboptimal for tracking packages, and I [plan to get rid of it if there ever comes time for a round of breaking changes](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/919). Otherwise, there is no way to get rid of it except `vis_drake_graph(targets_only = TRUE)`, which also gets rid of all the imports in the graph.

Comment: how's this idea to address Q3... https://gitlab.com/snippets/1902252

Comment: Sure, or the `subset` argument of `vis_drake_graph()`.

Comment: Could we add this as a feature to `vis_drake_graph`? Something like `remove_pkg_imports = TRUE` ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not think enough people will use it. Not the sort of thing I would hard-code in an exported function.

Comment: Gotcha. Our team feels the need for it since we're trying to use `drake` along with package development. So all entire codebase has explicit function calls. I'll just make a fork and modify things for our team.